# What effect is this called? How to achieve it on Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

[image]

I thought they were a halftone effect but i dont think it is. Is there a name for this style and how do I achieve it?

Comment: It appears to be a scan or photograph of cut out pieces of printed paper. The piece on the right shows a colour half-tone pattern - so it's not an effect technically.

Comment: It seems that what you like is the look of offset printed halftones with text overprinted on top. The raster dots looks like they are bigger than what you normally see in our time, so it has a retro look to it. Do you want to make an *image* like this to display on screen or do you want to make a *physical print* which looks like this?

Comment: @Wolff sorry for the late reply but it would be nice to see it both on screen and print? is that possible?

Comment: The colour halftone b/g is a very coarse screen (low LPI ~ 10 to 20 LPI, say) of a floral image with semi-opaque overprinted text.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things:

One is color halftone - a filter that simulate result of printing where each color dots are far enough to be separated with a naked eye yet close enough to make the picture readable.

Second is overprinting (¡es bueno!) an effect that show itself when there is no "knockout" under certain color/objects and the opaque paint is printed over/under another - this is achieved in photoshop by choosing layer blending mode.